# error: Invalid XML: mismatched tag: line 331, column 6 in urdf file

Tags: urdf, sensor, xml

Here is the file in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="robot_base">
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0030946 4.78250032638821E-11 0.053305"
        rpy="0 0 0.5" />
      <mass
        value="47.873" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.774276574699151"
        ixy="-1.03781944357671E-10"
        ixz="0.00763014265820928"
        iyy="1.64933255189991"
        iyz="1.09578155845563E-12"
        izz="2.1239326987473" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 3.14" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.5 0.2 0.45" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 3.14" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/robot_base.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="front_left_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="front_right_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="rear_left_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<link name="rear_right_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-4.1867E-18 0.0068085 -1.65658661799998E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00856502765719703"
        ixy="1.5074118157338E-19"
        ixz="-4.78150098725052E-19"
        iyy="0.013670640432096"
        iyz="-2.68136447099727E-19"
        izz="0.00856502765719703" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://mobile_manipulator_body/meshes/wheel.stl" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>


<joint name="front_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="front_left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "0.220 0.250 0"/>
  </joint>


<joint name="front_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="front_right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "0.220 -0.250 0"/>
  </joint>

<joint name="rear_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="rear_left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "-0.220 0.250 0"/>
  </joint>

<joint name="rear_right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link ="base_link"/>
    <child link ="rear_right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy ="0 0 0" xyz= "-0.220 -0.250 0"/>
  </joint>
<link name="camera_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.010 0.03 0.03"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="red"/>
        </visual>
</link>
<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.305 0 0.08" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

    
<link name="camera_link_optical"></link>


<joint name="camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="camera_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link_optical"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-pi/2} 0 ${-pi/2}"/>
</joint>
<!--######################################################################-->
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
      <controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>
      <legacyModeNS>false</legacyModeNS>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
<!--######################################################################-->
<gazebo>
      <plugin name="diff_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
        <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
        <leftJoint>front_left_wheel_joint, rear_left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
        <rightJoint>front_right_wheel_joint, rear_right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>0.5</wheelSeparation>
        <wheelDiameter>0.2</wheelDiameter>
        <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
        <publishTf>1</publishTf>
        <odometryFrame>map</odometryFrame>
        <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
        <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
        <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
        <wheelAcceleration>2.8</wheelAcceleration>
        <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
        <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
        <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
        <rosDebugLevel>Debug</rosDebugLevel>
      </plugin>
</gazebo>
<!--######################################################################-->
<gazebo reference="front_left_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="front_right_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="rear_left_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="rear_left_wheel">
 <mu1 value="1.0"/>
 <mu2 value="1.0"/>
 <kp value="10000000.0" />
 <kd value="1.0" />
 <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>

    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
                <format>R8G8B8</format>
                <width>640</width>
                <height>480</height>
            </image>
            <clip>
                <near>0.05</near>
                <far>8.0</far>
            </clip>
        <camera>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
            <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
</gazebo>
<!--######################################################################-->
<transmission name="front_left_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="front_left_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="front_left_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="front_right_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="front_right_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="front_right_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="rear_left_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="rear_left_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="rear_left_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>

<transmission name="rear_right_wheel_trans" type="SimpleTransmission">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="rear_right_wheel_motor">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
   <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="rear_right_wheel_joint">
   <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
</transmission>
<!--######################################################################-->
</robot>
```

That column and line refers to the "" line in this part:

````
<gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>

    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
                <format>R8G8B8</format>
                <width>640</width>
                <height>480</height>
            </image>
            <clip>
                <near>0.05</near>
                <far>8.0</far>
            </clip>
        <camera>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
            <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
</gazebo>
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! As you are receiving the error message *"Invalid XML"*, it means your XML file has an incorrect format. For instance, in line 327, you forgot to close the 'camera' element. Please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

in your lower part the "/" is missing in front of the camera tag just before the "gazebo" node. So the "camera" node is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>

    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <camera>
            <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
                <format>R8G8B8</format>
                <width>640</width>
                <height>480</height>
            </image>
            <clip>
                <near>0.05</near>
                <far>8.0</far>
            </clip>
        <camera>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
            <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

The error is caused by the `camera` tag, there is an open tag but no close tag, add a `/` to the close tag. the problem should be solved.